# Adding a variable to a variable in an if statement

Tags: python

I am trying to add the number of my function to the statement, and I cant figure it out.  Here is my function :

```
def hash_func(n):
    number = ("1234567890")
    x = 0
    for each_item in n:   
        if each_item in number:
            x = x + each_item  #this is the line where code goes wrong
    return x
print(hash_func("ironman3"))
```

any suggestions?  Thank you!

Comment: Please format your code. What does "I can't figure it out" mean? Are you having an error? Please read  [ask].

Comment: Sorry, I was wondering how I should add the specific number to X, meaning how do I add 3 to x, but if the function was ironman2 it would add 2 to x?

Comment: So you want to add all the numbers on a string together. What is `x + each_item` doing? How is your program not working?

Comment: In other words, what is the output you expect and what is the output you're getting for a specific input?

Comment: When I run x = x + each_item I get the error, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str', and I am very confused because shouldn't it just add the 3 to x?  Sorry I am new to this website, so had trouble with layout.

Comment: I am hoping that for "ironman3"

Comment: output should be 3, because thats the only number in it, but if its "help2thanks3" it will output 5

Comment: You're doing fine. Just add some of the comments you've made as an edit to your question so people can see it easier.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote good answers and accept one if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add a string character with an integer.
Convert the values to a numeric data type and it will work.

```
x = x + int(each_item)
```